# MariaDB refuses to execute my Procedure get a syntax error "CONN=3259"

Tags: mysql

I am trying to execute SQL code but it hits me with a syntax error from MariaDB. As far as I can tell the code is sound and MariaDB does not have a lot of examples to help illustrate the proper syntax.

I have already tried to and adding IN before each param but still, get the error. I have also tried adding a DELIMITER with no avail.

```
/*
    Procedure to put a buy order in Trade Table
 */

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE spTradePurchase(IN @tradeIdNum INT, IN @investimateId INT, IN @tradeType VARCHAR(32),
                               IN @tradePrice INT,
                               IN @tradeShareNum INT, IN @accountNumber INT
                               )
AS

BEGIN

INSERT INTO jw_group02_db.TRADE(TRADE_ID, INVEST_ID, TRADE_TYPE, TRADE_SHARE_AMT, ACC_NUM, TRADE_DATE, TRADE_SALE_PRICE)
    VALUES (@tradeIdNum,@investimteId,@tradeType,@tradeShareNum,@accountNumber,Date(UTC_DATE),@tradePrice);
    RETURN 1;
END;

/*
    Procedure to put a sell order in Trade Table
 */
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE spTradeSell(@tradeIdNum INT,@investimateId INT,@tradeType VARCHAR(32),
                               @tradePrice INT,
                               @tradeShareNum INT,@accountNumber INT
                               )
AS

BEGIN
    SET @shareVal = -1 * @tradeShareNum;

INSERT INTO jw_group02_db.TRADE(TRADE_ID, INVEST_ID, TRADE_TYPE, TRADE_SHARE_AMT, ACC_NUM, TRADE_DATE, TRADE_SALE_PRICE)
    VALUES (@tradeIdNum,@investimteId,@tradeType,@shareVal,@accountNumber,Date(UTC_DATE),@tradePrice);

END;
```

I should be getting a completed message like:

```
sql> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE simpleproc (OUT param1 INT)
      BEGIN
       SELECT COUNT(*) INTO param1 FROM jw_misraa_db.CUSTOMER;
      END
[2019-05-28 16:05:19] completed in 23 ms
```

EDIT: here is full error

```
[2019-05-28 17:03:53] [42000][1064] (conn=3259) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@tradeIdNum  INT(4) UNSIGNED, @investimateId INT(11) UNSIGNED,
[2019-05-28 17:03:53] [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@tradeIdNum  INT(4) UNSIGNED, @investimateId INT(11) UNSIGNED,
[2019-05-28 17:03:53] ' at line 1
[2019-05-28 17:03:53] Query is: CREATE PROCEDURE spTradePurchase( @tradeIdNum  INT(4) UNSIGNED, @investimateId INT(11) UNSIGNED,
[2019-05-28 17:03:53] @tradeType VARCHAR(32), @tradePrice INT(32) UNSIGNED,
[2019-05-28 17:03:53] @tradeShareNum INT(32) UNSIGNED, @accountNumber INT(4) UNSIGNED)
[2019-05-28 17:03:53] AS
[2019-05-28 17:03:53] BEGIN
[2019-05-28 17:03:53] INSERT INTO jw_group02_db.TRADE(TRADE_ID, INVEST_ID, TRADE_TYPE, TRADE_SHARE_AMT, ACC_NUM, TRADE_DATE, TRADE_SALE_PRICE)
[2019-05-28 17:03:53] VALUES (@tradeIdNum,@investimteId,@tradeType,@tradeShareNum,@accountNumber,DATE(NOW()),@tradePrice);
[2019-05-28 17:03:53] END
[2019-05-28 17:03:53] java thread: RMI TCP Connection(23)-127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Is that the Complete error message

Comment: Here is more of the error:

[2019-05-28 15:40:31] [42000][1064] (conn=3232) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@tradeIdNum INT,@investimateId INT,@tradeType VARCHAR(32),
[2019-05-28 15:40:31] [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@tradeIdNum INT,@investimateId INT,@tradeType VARCHAR(32),
[2019-05-28 15:40:31] ' at line 1

Comment: Error Solved. Remove the '@' on each param. and it executed just fine

Comment: I don't understand why these are sprocs. I see nothing procedural here